# How to fix tilemap bug in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

Does anyone know how to fix this kind of horrible bug when using Unity tile palettes? This happened to me when I added a new scene and created a new tile palette to use, then switched back to the first scene. My old tile palette got overwritten by a bunch of pink squares and the tiles in the first scene were replaced by stuff from the palette in the second scene. Reloading Unity does not fix the issue. The tiles remain pink and I cant work with them.

Tilemap glitch in tile palette

[image]

Tilemap glitch - replaced tiles in game

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the cause: when saving the second palette I saved it in the same folder as the first, and I think this messed everything up. As for fixing the issue, there was no easy way except to entirely delete the first palette and reimport it, then paint over the glitched tiles manually.